# the world('s) population speak/speaks

Tags: verbs

Which one is correct:

1- 4.23% of the world (world's) population SPEAKS Arabic.

2- 4.23% of the world (world's) population SPEAK Arabic.

Comment: Is it like "some of them speak Spanish"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case.  When you have a subject of a sentence which describes a portion (fraction, percentage, all, etc.), you do look to the object of the preposition for *its* number.  See Rule 9 in http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp "this Grammar Book online resource". For example, one would say "4% of teachers eat bread" but "4% of my house smells terrible."   So the correct answer in this case is "4.23% of the world's population speak**s** Arabic."

Answer (score 2):

The choice mostly depends on the object of the preposition. If the object of the preposition is plural it could be  *speak*. If the object of the preposition is singular, then *speaks* would be  correct — as in:

> 4.23% of the world speaks

But I believe we need to pay attention to the term *population* — which is a collective noun.

Comment: “Four out of every five dentists agree.  Only one out of every five doctors agrees.”  Ok, perhaps so.

Comment: @tchrist I personally agree with Mustafa, but you are right as well. "80% of the dentists agree. Only 20% of the doctors agree." This works the same way.